# Timepicker como uma barra arrastável

Tags: android, android-layout

É possível fazer um *timepicker* desta forma da imagem?
Para que eu possa colocar um range, de horas.
Se sim, há um exemplo ou uma biblioteca?
Se não, alguma sugestão?

#### Imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sim, é possível uma fazer uma customização do `Seekbar`, porém nativamente possui apenas um controle deslizante. Para criar 2 controles, se estiver com muita pressa, pode usar uma *lib* pronta. Veja alguns exemplos:

- [RangeBar](https://github.com/edmodo/range-bar)
- [range-seek-bar](https://code.google.com/p/range-seek-bar/)
- [RangeSeekBar](https://github.com/Larpon/RangeSeekBar)
- [android-range-seek-bar](https://github.com/yahoo/android-range-seek-bar)

**Mas não é só isso.** Depois você deve definir o valor máximo do `SeekBar` em `1440`, que representa exatamente a quantidade de minutos em 24 horas. Isso considerando que não usará o fator "segundos". Depois o calculo é simples:

```
int hours = valueMax / 60;     // o resultado representa as horas
int minutes = valueMax % 60;   // o resultado representa os minutos
```

Isso você terá que fazer para cada um dos controles deslizantes.

Comment: @ramaral você conhece `timepicker` em formato de `seekbar`? Essa seria minha sugestão, que poderia até dar um pouco de trabalho, mas funcionará.

Comment: eu pesquisando também só achei neste estilo que vc fez, estou testando aqui e lhe retorno. Estou usando este https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/3996

Comment: @HenriqueMendes eu até tenho algo quase pronto aqui, mas não posso te auxiliar agora. Tenta ai, qualquer coisa se não conseguir, me dá um toque. Mas a lógica é essa mesmo. Se fosse o caso de usar em uma aplicação minha, eu faria desta forma.

Comment: Usei a biblioteca que passei acima, e sua lógica funcionou, para trazer os minutos e horas, muito obrigado!

Comment: @AckLay, não, não conheço mas a sua solução é viável. Lembre que o `@nome` não funciona sempre, encontrei o seu comentário por acaso.